# Generate alert if percentage drop is more than 70% for metricX at any point of time for 5 mins

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql, prometheus-operator

I would like to generate alert for example when counter `metricX` drops more than 70% at any point of time for 5 mins.

Following would be my rule YAML file to generate alert:

```
groups:
- name: MetricX dip
  rules:
  - alert: MetricX dip by more than 70%
    expr: 
    for: 0m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      descriptions: MetricX has been dropped by more than 70%
```

I would like to see some guide on how can I write `promQL` expressions in rule file to measure drop in percentage of metricX at any point of time for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After understanding `promql` throughly, this is what I implemented in simple form which satisfies my requirement.

```
(-100 * rate(MetricX[2m]) / rate(MetricX[5m] offset 1m)) > 70
```

`MetricX` is counter. So, I used `rate` in  computing drop in percentage. My prometheus `scrape_interval` is 1 min. So, dip is computed over 2 mins
that follows 5 mins.

I hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
rate(metricX[2m]) < 0.7 * (rate(metricX[2m] offset 5m))
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since you did not include `rate` function. Without it you don't know the change of value over time. In this case, avg. rate of increase per second. If metric is gauge then you would use `delta` or `idelta`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Added `rate()` to the answer!